# linkedin api search_profile results not what i expected

Tags: linkedin-api

When searching for a specific name with a city keyword via the LinkedIn search bar in my browser, I get results that make sense (first and/or last name match, location matches). When I invoke the search_profile api, the api results do not agree with the browser results.

I'm running Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04. Importing linkedin obtained via "pip install python-linkedin" resulting in python-linkedin version 4.1 and requests version 2.5.1. The authorization and application instantiation are successful.

Here's the code:

```
f = 'Joe'   # names changed to protect the guilty
l = 'Black' # names changed to protect the guilty

p = app.search_profile(selectors=[{'people': ['first-name', 
                                              'last-name', 
                                              'id',
                                              'location',
                                              'num-connections']}], 
                       params={'lastName': '{}'.format(l),
                               'firstName': '{}'.format(f),
                               'location': {'country': {'code': 'us'}, 'name': 'Greater Nashville Area'}})

print 'from search_profile for {} {}'.format(f, l)
for s in p['people']['values']:
    print s['firstName'], s['lastName'], s['id'], s['numConnections'], s['location']
```

Any ideas?